# Why can't the core threads of a thread pool in Java be reused in the initial phase?

Tags: java, multithreading

I recently had a question looking at the source code of **ThreadPoolExecutor**: If thread pool represents the reuse of existing threads to reduce the overhead of thread creation or destruction, why not reuse core threads in the initial phase? That is, when the current number of threads is less than the number of core threads, first check whether there are core threads that have completed the task, if so, reuse. Why not? Instead of creating a new thread before the number of core threads is reached, does this violate thread pool design principles?

The following is a partial comment on the *addWorker()* method in ThreadPoolExecutor

> - @param firstTask the task the new thread should run first (or null if none). Workers are created with an initial first task (in method execute()) to bypass queuing when there are fewer than corePoolSize threads (in which case we always start one), or when the queue is full (in which case we must bypass queue). Initially idle threads are usually created via prestartCoreThread or to replace other dying workers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually requested already: [JDK-6452337](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6452337). A core libraries developer has noted:

> I like this idea, but ThreadPoolExecutor is already complicated enough.

Keep in mind that `corePoolSize` is an essential part of `ThreadPoolExecutor` and is saying how many workers are always active/idle *at least*. Reaching this number just naturally takes a very short time. You set `corePoolSize` according to your needs and it's expected that the workload will meet this number.

My assumption is that optimizing this "warm-up phase" – taking it for granted that this *will* actually increase efficiency – is not worth it. I can't quantify for you what additional complexity this optimization will bring, I'm not developing Java Core libraries, but I assume that it's not worth it.

You can think of it like that: The "warm-up phase" is constant while the thread pool will run for an undefined amount of time. In an ideal world, the initial phase actually should take no time at all, the workload should be there as you create the thread pool. So you are thinking about an optimization that optimizes something that is not the expected thread pool state.

The thread workers will have to be created at some point anyways. This optimization only delays the creation. Imagine you have a `corePoolSize` of 10, so there is the overhead of creating 10 threads at least. This overhead won't change if you do it later. Yes, resources are also taken later but here I'm asking if the thread pool is configured correctly in the first place: Is `corePoolSize` correct, does it meet the current workload?

Notice that `ThreadPoolExecutor` has methods like [`setCorePoolSize(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize(int)) and [`allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean)) and more that allow you to configure the thread pool according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Conceptually, corePoolSize is the fewest number of running or idle threads in the thread pool.Indeed, reusing idle core threads is not worth the effort.I also think the highly uncertain behavior of getting the execution state of a thread and then doing something about it is not worth the cost.I'm now going through the source code and the comments, trying to figure out where the reuse of thread pools is going.Thanks again!

Comment: @Jack_Du You are welcome! The method `execute` is a good starting point.